# Null pointer exception with a method call

Tags: arraylist, nullpointerexception

Ok this is the code for one section of my switch statement:

```
 case 1: {
               System.out.print("Member ID: ");
               int key = in.nextInt();
               while(members.findItemByKey(key) == -1){
                   System.out.print("That is an invalid member ID!\nEnter a new one: ");
                   key = in.nextInt();
               }


               System.out.print("ISBN: ");

               int book = in.nextInt();
             while(books.findItemByKey(book) == -1){
                 System.out.println("That book is not in the system.\nPlease make a new choice: ");
                 book = in.nextInt();
             }
             while(stock.findItemByKey(book) != -1){  
               try {
                m = members.get(members.findItemByKey(key));
                t = books.get(books.findItemByKey(book));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

               if(m.checkOut(t) == true){
                   stock.removeItem(t);
               }
             }

           }
```

Here is the method that is calling:

```
public int findItemByKey(int key){

    for(E e: list)
    {
        if(e.getKey() == key){
            return findItem(e);
        }
    }


    return -1;
}

        public int findItem(E item){

    if (item == null){
        for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
            if(list[i]==null)
                return i;
    }else {
        for( int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
            if (item.equals(list[i]))
                return i;

    }

    return -1;
}
```

Ok, I know there's a lot to look at here, but here's what's happening. When I enter an invalid member ID, it functions properly and keeps asking the user for a new member ID until a valid one is entered. Now when I enter a book, regardless of whether I enter a valid or invalid book, I am getting a null pointer exception thrown by this line:

```
if(e.getKey() == key)
```

books, members, and stock are all arraylists defined the same way in my code. I don't understand why I'm having this exception thrown with books and not with the members. The classes for book and member are defined the same way, both have the same getKey method within them.

Maybe there's just too much going on in this question for anyone to be able to really see what's going on. Basically I just can't understand why I get a null pointer exception with the one and not with the other.

Edit: Decided I should post the getKey() method for each class.

```
 public int getKey()
  {
        return ISBN;
  }
```

Is the one for books

```
  public int getKey()
  {
        return memberId;
  }
```

Is the one for members.

ISBN is the identifier for books and memberId is the identifier for my members. Everything looks like it's calling the same things, but it errors for books and not for members. Just don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either this `e` is null or the value returned from the statement `e.getKey()` is null.

You have to make sure that the list doesn't contain a `null` element and then their `key`s should also be not-null.

If you want to ignore these values being null, you can do like:

```
if(e!=null && e.getKey()!=null && e.getKey() == key){
     //statements here.
}
```

Comment: e.getKey()!=null is undefined for argument types int, null.

Comment: I just took that part out and left it as
    if(e!=null && e.getKey() == key){
       //statements
    }

Comment: Oh I see. Can you please tell me where is this list being populated/initialized?